# How to make the CPU take an appropriate amount of sticks in this python nims game

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
import random

def print_move(current_player,row,stick_quantity):
  current_player = current_player
  print(f"{current_player} takes {stick_quantity} sticks from {row} row")

 
sticks = [1, 3, 5, 7]

def nims():
  for count, stick in enumerate(sticks):
    print(count+1,stick * "|")


print("Welcome to Nim!")
name = input("Enter name: ")
current_player = random.choice([name, "CPU"])
print('game is starting',(current_player),'will be going first')
 
while True:
  if current_player == name:
    row = int(input("Which row would you like to take sticks from? "))
    stick_quantity = int(input("How many sticks would you like to take? "))
    sticks[row - 1] -= stick_quantity    
    print_move(current_player,row,stick_quantity)
    if current_player == name:
      current_player = "CPU"
    else:
      current_player = name
  
  elif current_player == "CPU":
    row = random.choice([1,2,3,4])
    stick_quantity = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
    sticks[row - 1] -= stick_quantity
    print_move(current_player,row,stick_quantity)
    if current_player == "CPU":
      current_player = name
    else:
      current_player = "CPU"


  nims()
```

In the nims game I've created I've created a CPU that removes a certain amounts of sticks from a certain amount of row. I've made it so that it is a random choice, but I've had this issue, where the CPU will decided to take large amount of sticks from a row where the sticks are already gone. I want it so that the CPU can only take an appropriate amount of sticks, and if the CPU removes a bigger amount of sticks from a row, where the sticks aren't there, I want a loop that'll loop until the CPU takes an appropriate amount of sticks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First, you need to know the **rules that tell you** the correct number of sticks to take. That is not a programming question, but a logic question. We can't tell you what your program should do; we can only answer questions about how to do something, or about why something turned out differently from what you expect. But either way, it is [your responsibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) before asking to *focus* the question on the *specific part* of the program where there appears to be a problem (and to figure out where that is).

Comment: Some suggestions: 1. Format your code, preferably with _black_, or at least using 4-space indents. 2. Replace the word "appropriate" in title with "valid" to reduce misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

> I want a loop that'll loop until the CPU takes an appropriate amount of sticks

While your plan may not be sound, let's just do it.

```py
...
  elif current_player == "CPU":
    # We may try infinitely until we have a good luck.
    while True:
      # Just roll the dice.
      row = random.choice([1,2,3,4])
      stick_quantity = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

      # When we finally have a valid `stick_quantity`,
      # exit the loop to continue.
      if stick_quantity <= sticks[row - 1]:
        break

    sticks[row - 1] -= stick_quantity
...
```

Note that there are better ways to ensure that generated numbers be valid. For example --

```py
...
    # Choose a row which is not empty.
    row = random.choice(
      [
        i + 1
        for i, quantity in enumerate(sticks) 
        if quantity > 0
      ]
    )
    # Choose a quantity that does not exceed maximum.
    stick_quantity = random.randint(0, sticks[row - 1]) + 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a control for the CPU in order to check if enough sticks are available in the chosen row. If not, the CPU should select a different row or choose a smaller quantity of sticks.

Basically the CPU behaviour could be designed as follows:

```
def cpu_turn():
    while True:
        row = random.randint(1, len(sticks))
        if sticks[row - 1] > 0:
            max_sticks = min(sticks[row - 1], 7)  # Maximum sticks CPU can take
            stick_quantity = random.randint(1, max_sticks)
            sticks[row - 1] -= stick_quantity
            print_move(current_player, row, stick_quantity)
            break
```

and then:

```
elif current_player == "CPU":
   cpu_turn()
   if current_player == "CPU":
      current_player = name
   else:
      current_player = "CPU"
```

Comment: Does it have to be a function, or can you just make it without a function?

Comment: You can take the function out and put everything in the code. Using functions makes the code clearer and easier to manage / fix, but it's not strictly mandatory to use them